# Does 4.0-72mm on the lens when equivalent focal length is 24-432mm mean crop factor of 6×?

Tags: focal-length, crop-factor

The Samsung WB250F has 4.0mm-72.0mm printed on its lens, and its 35mm equivalent focal length range is 24mm-432mm.

Does that mean it has a 6x crop factor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this mean crop-factor of your camera (Samsung WB250F) is 6

Focal length is one of the ways to calculate crop-factor, divide 35 equivalent of focal length to the focal length on the lens

P.S. The canonical way (as far as I know) is to use the size of the sensor and compare it with the size of fullframe sensor. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_factor#Common_crop_factors) for reference

Comment: What does it mean by it has a '6x' crop factor? How much times WB250F's sensor smaller than a full frame sensor?

Comment: @user152435 That would probably make a decent *separate* question (assuming it hasn't already been asked and answered).

Comment: @user152435 Short answer: Crop factors are based on *linear* measurements, not *area* measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Compact cameras label their lenses in "35mm equivalent focal length" which is pretty illogical in my opinion. Thankfully other non-35mm formats such as m4/3 and APS-C and the various medium and large formats do not do the same.

What this means is that your camera with its tiny (roughly 1/2.3" format [though that's not the actual measurement, just a name, consult Wikipedia for more] I believe) sensor and 4-72mm lens has the same field of view that a 35mm sensor and 24-432mm lens would have.